# Play video clash VideoView

Tags: android

I am doing an app which can play video , but when I run it , it clash and the logcat "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity"

What should I do for my code ?
thanks

```
public class Video extends AppCompatActivity {
VideoView myVideoView;
String localFilePath;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    localFilePath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test;
    VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
    myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(localFilePath));
    myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    myVideoView.start();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is because the activity you are trying to apply the dialog theme to is extending `ActionBarActivity` which requires the `AppCompat` theme to be applied.

Change ur theme in style.xml ..

```
 <!--
         Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
         by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
     -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
```

Use it in manifest..

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Use `Toolbar`.put this code top of your xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />
```

Comment: Thank you for reply , I had try to change it , no clash , But it bring to a page which is empty , all my videoview and button had disappeared, what should I do ?

Comment: Where is your `setContentView` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help , it works now . But all my action are disappear , what if I wanna keep all the action bar ?

Comment: Than you , how about the action bar for other normal activity ?